# EF CodeFirst AddColumn to a Self join Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So i'm using asp identity
the ApplicationUser has FriendRequests , this is what I did

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public ApplicationUser()
     {
          FriendRequests = new Collection<ApplicationUser>();
     }

     public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> FriendRequests {get; set;}

}
```

And here is my Fluent Api Mapping

```
         modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
         .HasMany(x => x.FriendRequests)
         .WithMany()
         .Map(x => 
                {
                    x.MapLeftKey("UserRequestingID");
                    x.MapRightKey("UserBeingRequestedID");
                    x.ToTable("FriendRequests");
                });
```

This Creates a Table "FriendRequests" with two Columns "UserRequestingID" and "UserBeingRequestedID".

I want to Add an additional Column "isIgnored" to this table , how can I do it ?
can I even do it this way ? or shall I just create a new class ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`many-to-many` relationship via mapping is supported only if the junction table does not contain other columns than the PK. So yes, if you want to include additional column, then you need to create explicit entity and set up 2 `one-to-many` relationships.

Something like this:

*Model:*

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<FriendRequest> FriendRequests {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<FriendRequest> FriendRequested {get; set;}
}

public class FriendRequest
{
    public string UserRequestingID { get; set; }
    public string UserBeingRequestedID { get; set; }
    public bool IsIgnored { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserRequesting { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserBeingRequested { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.UserRequestingID, e.UserBeingRequestedID });

modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.UserRequesting)
    .WithMany(e => e.FriendRequests)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserRequestingID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.UserBeingRequested)
    .WithMany(e => e.FriendRequested)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserBeingRequestedID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```